# Failed to rsync file to AWS: no such file or directory

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

I am trying to run a somewhat computing intensive job on Amazon Web Services and when syncing my .exe to the created instance, I get the following mistake

```
rsync -azv --progress -e "ssh -i /Users/xxxxx/.ssh/MyKeyPair.pem" /Users/xxxxx/Dev/ql-analytics/QL-Extensions/cmake-build-debug/QL_Extensions.exe yyyyyyy.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
building file list ... 
rsync: link_stat "/Users/xxxxxxx/Dev/ql-analytics/QL-Extensions/cmake-build-debug/QL_Extensions.exe" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

I know for a fact that the path link stat exists on my machine. I can't see why the command doesn't work...Please save me!

Thanks
Amine

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

My mistake was in the source file. Should have been:
/Users/xxxxxxx/Dev/ql-analytics/QL-Extensions/cmake-build-debug/QL_Extensions instead of ....../QL_Extensions.exe